# Putting lists into a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have no idea why in every Value in my Map is putted the same last record. 
The Key is ok, but in every iteration my list is putted into everyone record in map.
I dont understand why..

Could someone help ?

```
    HashMap<Long, LinesEntity> xlsMapped = new HashMap<>();
    MapEntity mapEntity = new MapEntity();

    LinesEntity linesEntity = new LinesEntity();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //read first line
    String line = br.readLine();
    String array[];

    long mapKey = 0;

        while (line != null) {

            array = line.split(",");

            list.clear();
            for (String cell : array) {

                list.add(cell);
            }
            line = br.readLine();

            linesEntity.setSingleLine(list);

            dataService.saveOne(linesEntity);

            xlsMapped.put(mapKey, linesEntity);
            mapKey++;

        }

     // mapEntity.setMapa(xlsMapped);
    //  dataService.save(mapEntity);

}
```

Comment: You are adding a reference to the same list over and over again.  Since every reference in your map is to a single list, when you update the contents of that list (via `clear()` and `add()`) you see that change reflected, no matter which reference you use to look at the one, single, list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create new `linesEntity` and `list` object instances for each loop:

```
while (line != null) {

    linesEntity = new LinesEntity(); // create a new LinesEntity for this loop execution
    list = new ArrayList()

    array = line.split(",");
```

Which means that technically you don't need to create them at the top, just declare them:

```
LinesEntity linesEntity;
ArrayList<String> list;
```